# Semantic UI Bottom Sidebar Increase Size

Tags: javascript, css, semantic-ui

Is there any way to increase the size (height) of the bottom version of the Semantic UI [Sidebar](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar.html)?

If you add a wide class to the div element, it cuts off the bar. "wide" is only used for vertical sidebars, not for horizontal ones. "wide" only affects the width of the sidebar, not its height.

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dr480mnu/) of an attempt at a solution.

HTML

```
<div class="ui bottom sidebar deep vertical inverted menu" id="bottom-side">
    <div class="header item">Bottom Sidebar menu</div>
    <a class=item>Foo</a>
    <a class=item>Foo</a>
    <a class=item>Foo</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#bottom-side').sidebar('toggle');
});
```

CSS

```
.ui.deep.bottom.sidebar {
    height: 400px;
}

.ui.deep.active.bottom.sidebar {
    height: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The semantic UI CSS is using `!important` when setting the height, so you need to use it as well to override it. It looks like you also need a negative top margin equal to the height. Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m4th0hb3/1/

```
.ui.deep.active.bottom.sidebar {
    height: 400px !important;
    margin-top: -400px !important;
}
```

Comment: If this didn't work for anyone, try: .ui.bottom.sidebar, .ui.top.sidebar